# How to create a Bot with LUIS to support multiple languages in Bot Framework (C# SDK)

Tags: botframework, azure-language-understanding

I have created a bot using bot framework (C# SDK) and with the LUIS currently trained with English utterannces. Now I want it to support German language. For example, Bot should ask user for their language preference and store it in User DataBag and later respond it in that language. User should be able to change their prefernece at any time.

- Given the situation, what is the easiest way to achieve it?
- Do I need to create a seperate LUIS model to support German language or is their a way to reuse English model?
- I am using FormFlow and there are lot of built-in. How can I translate them on run time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you will need multiple LUIS models, one per each language.

Regarding FormFlow, you might want to consider [localizing the form content](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/bot-framework/dotnet/bot-builder-dotnet-formflow-localize).

[This article](https://www.microsoft.com/developerblog/2017/01/21/orchestrating-multiple-bots-with-multilingual-support/) describes a bit the challenges of doing multilingual bots, though the code is Node.js